# svn revert a single property on a directory?

Tags: svn, properties

How can I revert one of several properties on a directory from svn command line?

My svn trunk has a property svn:externals to import an external repo.

```
/trunk
  svn:external = /external/trunk
```

When I set up a new branch foo, the external is changed to point to a branch as well:

```
/branches/foo
  svn:external = /external/branches/foo
```

Sometimes when I merge a branch back into the trunk, that property gets copied over and I end up with:

```
/trunk
  svn:external = /external/branches/foo
```

Normally I could run `svn revert . --depth=empty` to undo the property merge, but there are other properties on the dir that would be reverted as well, specifically `svn:mergeinfo`. From my GUI client I can revert individual properties pretty easily, but I don't always remember to do so. Is there a way to do the same thing directly from svn cmd line, or do I need to write some crazy wrapper for `svn propget` to get and undo the diff?

Answer (score 9):

`svn propset svn:externals "$(svn propget svn:externals . -r HEAD)" .`

this sets the property to the HEAD value.  This is a valid workaround since `revert` can only be applied to *all* properties, and doesn't exist for *individual* properties.

Answer (score 0):

For my future reference more than for you, seeing as you probably have the answer...

```
svn propget PROPNAMETOREVERT `svn info | perl -ne 'print if s/URL: (.*)/\1/'` | perl -ne 'chomp; print' | svn propset PROPNAMETOREVERT  -F - .
```

Worked for me (on a one line property, might need modification for one with multiple lines).

Which could clearly do with being a script :-)